# How to use an int as an array of ints/bools?

Tags: c++, memory-management, bitwise-operators, integer

I noticed while making a program that a lot of my `int` type variables never went above ten.  I figure that because an `int` is 2 bytes at the shortest (1 if you count `char`), so I should be able to store 4 `unsigned ints` with a max value of 15 in a short int, and I know I can access each one individually using `>>` and `<<`:

```
short unsigned int SLWD = 11434;
S is (SLWD >> 12), L is ((SLWD << 4) >> 12),
W is ((SLWD << 8) >> 12), and D is ((SLWD << 8) >> 12)
```

However, I have no idea how to encompase this in a function of class, since any type of `GetVal()` function would have to be of type `int`, which defeats the purpose of isolating the bits in the first place.

Comment: How many of these small ints are you storing?  Are you sure you'll see a benefit to packing them in this way?  You know what they say about premature optimization.  If you're doing this for fun, ok, but I'll bet you won't see a measurable performance improvement.

Comment: It's always good to tag your questions with the language you're asking about...

Comment: I agree with @Michael Petrotta on this.  In many cases the code changes of having additional OR and bit shift instructions will increase memory usage more than shaving off a few bits will save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remember the [Rules of Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization). But this is possible in C or C++ using bitfields:

```
struct mystruct {
    unsigned int smallint1 : 3; /* 3 bits wide, values  0 -- 7 */
    signed int   smallint2 : 4; /* 4 bits wide, values -8 -- 7 */
    unsigned int boolean   : 1; /* 1 bit  wide, values  0 -- 1 */
};
```

It's worth noting that while you gain by not requiring so much storage, you lose because it becomes more costly to access everything, since each read or write now has a bunch of bit twiddling mechanics associated with it. Given that storage is cheap, it's probably not worth it.

Edit: You can also use `vector<bool>` to store 1-bit bools; but beware of it because it doesn't act like a normal `vector`! In particular, it doesn't provide iterators. It's sufficiently different that it's fair to say a `vector<bool>` is not actually a `vector`. Scott Meyers wrote very clearly on this topic in 'Effective STL'.

Comment: I suppose that the only time it'd actually be useful is if I literally had hundreds values being used simlutaneously.  But it is nice to know I can make a bool thats actually only 1 bit. ^^

Comment: talking about 1-bit bools reminded me of vector<bool>, see edited answer.

Comment: Hundreds of values will still only save you hundreds or thousands of bytes... you need to be talking tens or hundreds of thousands of instances for this to start to matter a lot. (Of course there are many cases where you do have that many instances...)

Comment: sizeof(mystruct) is 4 on my compiler. Beware of struct padding.

Comment: @Justicle: +1 Good point. The padding kills all the savings. The answer is to pack more values into the struct so it's 32 or 64 bits wide (depending on implementation).

Comment: `int smallint2 : 4;` is ambiguous; you need to specify `signed int smallint2 : 4;` to be sure it can hold negative values.

Comment: Per @Justicle's point, the compiler is likely to pad the structure to align to the largest declared native type, regardless of bitfields. So replacing `int` with `char` here will likely restore its size to 1 byte. (On the flip side, the compiler may get finicky if you give them *different* types, so you're best off declaring all your bitfields with the type with the desired final alignment rather than minimizing each individual declaration.)

Answer (score 2):

In C, and for the sole purpose of saving space, you can reinterpret the unsigned short as a structure with [bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) (or use such structure without messing with reinterpretations):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct bf_
{
   unsigned  x : 4;
   unsigned  y : 4;
   unsigned  z : 4;
   unsigned  w : 4;
} bf;


int main(void)
{
   unsigned short i = 5;
   bf *bitfields = (bf *) &i;

   bitfields->w = 12;
   printf("%d\n", bitfields->x);
   // etc..

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof(bf) is 4 on my compiler. Beware of struct padding.

Comment: +1, same as Chris. That could be incredibly powerful. If only there were favourite answers...

Comment: Justicle: you're right. Better to go for structs with the same size of a word (in our case, 32 bit).

Answer (score 1):

That's a very common technique. You usually allocate an array of the larger primitive type (e.g., ints or longs), and have some abstraction to deal with the mapping. If you're using an OO language, it's usually a good idea to actually define some sort of BitArray or SmartArray or something like that, and impement a getVal() that takes an index. The important thing is to make sure you hide the details of the internal representation (e.g., for when you move between platforms).

That being said, most mainstream languages already have this functionality available.
If you just want bits, [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) has a good list.
If you want more than bits, you can still find something, or implement it yourself with a similar interface. Take a look at the Java [BitSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)  for reference

Comment: "The important thing is to make sure you hide the details of the internal representation (e.g., for when you move between platforms)." Portability may not be important, access speed may be more important.